# Is there a way to automate deployment of user certificates with a Microsoft enterprise CA?

Tags: certificate, active-directory, windows-server-2016

Users can request certificates from our enterprise CA via the AD Certificate Services web app or the certificate manager MMC snap-in.  If I have a large number of users who wish to do this, is there any way to automate deployment of these certificates so that I can issue one to each of a group of users without their intervention?

Answer (score 1):

You can use certificate autoenrollment feature. A quick guide on deploying user certificates from Microsoft: [Certificate Deployment for Users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj129709(v=ws.11))

I wrote a comprehensive whitepaper on this, including basic information on certificate enrollment processor, technical details on autoenrollment and sample configuration: [Certificate Autoenrollment in Windows Server 2016](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/certificate-autoenrollment-in-windows-server-2016-summary.aspx)